# ReactNative - Using FlatList and redux to update is slow

Tags: react-native, react-redux

My `FlatList` displays Post and has a More button at the bottom right.
Press the More button to see additional buttons.

I implemented this using `immutability-helper` 's `update`, but it slows down when there is a lot of data (release mode).

This only happens on poorly performing devices.
Slow on iPhone 6
This is normal on the Galaxy S10.

Could there be another good implementation method ??

```
  [CHANGE_POST_EXPAND]: (state, action) => {
        const { index, expandState } = action.payload;
        return {
          ...state,
          postList: update(state.postList, {
            [index]: { isExpand: { $set: expandState } },
          }),
        };
      },


<SwipeListView
  disableRightSwipe
  style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.GRAY_LV0 }}
  data={postList}
  initialNumToRender={5}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  onEndReached={onEndReached}
  refreshing={refreshing}
  onRefresh={onRefresh}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => (item.postUID.toString())}
  contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  renderHiddenItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}
      onPress={() => hideItem(item.postUID)}
    >
      <View style={{
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: Colors.GRAY_LV3,
        width: 75,
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderBottomColor: Colors.GRAY_LV0,
      }}
      >
        <Text style={{
          color: Colors.GRAY_LV7,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          fontFamily: Fonts.NANUMGOTHIC,
          fontSize: addFontSize(14),
        }}
        >
          HIDE
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )}
  rightOpenValue={-75}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used  `Redux` before
In projects that are big and that we have a lot of tree components
It is not good at all
I found a great alternative
Both simple and high performance
this Doc is [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beep)